# matplotlib 3.0.0, cannot import name 'get_backend' from 'matplotlib'

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

Using Windows 10, anaconda as a package manager. I have a base environment running python 3.7 where matplotlib works fine. When I create a new environment and install both keras and matplotlib, I start to run into problems:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1111, in <module>
    rcParamsOrig = RcParams(rcParams.copy())
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 891, in __getitem__
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 40, in <module>
    import matplotlib._constrained_layout as constrained_layout
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_constrained_layout.py", line 52, in <module>
    from matplotlib.legend import Legend
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\legend.py", line 43, in <module>
    from matplotlib.offsetbox import HPacker, VPacker, TextArea, DrawingArea
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\offsetbox.py", line 33, in <module>
    from matplotlib.image import BboxImage
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 19, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
  File "C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 46, in <module>
    from matplotlib import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_backend'
```

Any suggestions? This is a fresh installation of conda. All I've done to get here is run `conda create --name keras_env keras matplotlib`, enter the environment, and try to import matplotlib. These are the packages conda installs:

```
## Package Plan ##

environment location: C:\...\Anaconda3\envs\keras_env

added / updated specs:
- keras
- matplotlib


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

_tflow_select:       2.2.0-eigen
absl-py:             0.5.0-py36_0
astor:               0.7.1-py36_0
blas:                1.0-mkl
ca-certificates:     2018.03.07-0
certifi:             2018.10.15-py36_0
cycler:              0.10.0-py36h009560c_0
freetype:            2.9.1-ha9979f8_1
gast:                0.2.0-py36_0
grpcio:              1.12.1-py36h1a1b453_0
h5py:                2.8.0-py36h3bdd7fb_2
hdf5:                1.10.2-hac2f561_1
icc_rt:              2017.0.4-h97af966_0
icu:                 58.2-ha66f8fd_1
intel-openmp:        2019.0-118
jpeg:                9b-hb83a4c4_2
keras:               2.2.4-0
keras-applications:  1.0.6-py36_0
keras-base:          2.2.4-py36_0
keras-preprocessing: 1.0.5-py36_0
kiwisolver:          1.0.1-py36h6538335_0
libpng:              1.6.35-h2a8f88b_0
libprotobuf:         3.6.0-h1a1b453_0
markdown:            3.0.1-py36_0
matplotlib:          3.0.0-py36hd159220_0
mkl:                 2019.0-118
mkl_fft:             1.0.6-py36hdbbee80_0
mkl_random:          1.0.1-py36h77b88f5_1
numpy:               1.15.3-py36ha559c80_0
numpy-base:          1.15.3-py36h8128ebf_0
openssl:             1.0.2p-hfa6e2cd_0
pip:                 10.0.1-py36_0
protobuf:            3.6.0-py36he025d50_0
pyparsing:           2.2.2-py36_0
pyqt:                5.9.2-py36h6538335_2
python:              3.6.7-h33f27b4_0
python-dateutil:     2.7.3-py36_0
pytz:                2018.5-py36_0
pyyaml:              3.13-py36hfa6e2cd_0
qt:                  5.9.6-vc14h1e9a669_2
scipy:               1.1.0-py36h4f6bf74_1
setuptools:          40.4.3-py36_0
sip:                 4.19.8-py36h6538335_0
six:                 1.11.0-py36_1
sqlite:              3.25.2-hfa6e2cd_0
tensorboard:         1.11.0-py36he025d50_0
tensorflow:          1.11.0-eigen_py36h346fd36_0
tensorflow-base:     1.11.0-eigen_py36h45df0d8_0
termcolor:           1.1.0-py36_1
tornado:             5.1.1-py36hfa6e2cd_0
vc:                  14.1-h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime:      14.15.26706-h3a45250_0
werkzeug:            0.14.1-py36_0
wheel:               0.32.2-py36_0
wincertstore:        0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0
yaml:                0.1.7-hc54c509_2
zlib:                1.2.11-h8395fce_2
```

Comment: _have a base environment running python 3.7 where matplotlib works fine._ It's best not to touch the base environment.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12601) and has been fixed [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/12604). The fix will be available in matplotlib 3.0.1, which is scheduled to be release within the next few days.

Until then you may either use python <= 3.6.6 with matplotlib 3.0.0. Or you may use matplotlib 2.2.3 or you may try the fix proposed in [the linked issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12601), namely to create a matplotlibrc file in one of the paths where matplotlib would find it.

Comment: This is in python 3.6.7, so that alone doesn't solve it. But using matplotlib 2.2.3 works, so I will just keep it downgraded.

Comment: @user121664: It is the issue; the change that broke matplotlib 3.0.0 in Python 3.7 was also merged into Python 3.6.7. You can see the commit [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/d45a9613402b686f8afd3dd5b6acf8141f14d711). Python 3.6.6 would probably be fine, and once matplotlib 3.0.1 comes out, matplotlib 3.0.1 shouldn't have the compatibility issues.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install matplotlib
```

Worked perfectly for me

Comment: The accepted answer says that this was an issue with matplotlib, which has since been fixed. How does this answer relate to the situation?

Answer (score 1):

It is a [issue](https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib/issues/559) with tikzplotlib and matplotlib > 3.8. Matplotlib 3.6 deprecates `pgf.common_texification`.

To solve it, you should replace `mpl.common_texification` with `mpl._tex_escape` in `_axes.py`:

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import _tex_escape as mpl_common_texification
```

Comment: Worked for me, thanks for posting the exact solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

works perfectly!

Comment: The accepted answer says that this was an issue with matplotlib, which has since been fixed. How does this answer relate to the situation?

Answer (score 0):

Simply install the appropriate version:

run this in your Jupyter notebook

```
!pip3 uninstall matplotlib -y
!pip3 install matplotlib==3.0.1
```

or in terminal:

```
pip3 uninstall matplotlib -y
pip3 install matplotlib==3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

matplotlib version: 3.8.1

The issue was in _axes.py (in tikzplotlib).
Location: \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\tikzplotlib

Please comment the below lines in the file that was problematic and now I am able to generate tex.

```
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import (
            common_texification as mpl_common_texification,
        )
    
       def _common_texification(string):
       
       #Work around <https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/15493>
       return mpl_common_texification(string).replace("&", "\\&")
    
       title = _common_texification(title)
       xlabel = _common_texification(xlabel)
       ylabel = _common_texification(ylabel)
     
 #pgfplots_ticklabels.append(_common_texification(label))
       pgfplots_ticklabels.append(label)
```